# Strange user connection with react native firebase authentication module

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-signin

Since few days I am trying to deploy my app on android store.
I am using react-native firebase with authentication module (6.7.1)
I then started with internal tests on which I only added 2 mail I can have access for tests.

The code look like this

```
GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: config.GOOGLE_WEB_CLIENT_ID })

_onGoogleButtonPress = async () => {
    try {
      const { idToken } = await GoogleSignin.signIn()
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken)
      let response = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
      if (!response.user.emailVerified) throw new Error(translate('ERROR_GOOGLE_MAIL_VERIFIED'))
      response.user['type'] = 'google'
      let result = await getToken(response.user)
      if (!Object.prototype.toString.call(result) !== 'error') this._loadDetails(result)
      else throw new Error(translate('ERROR_GOOGLE_CONNECT'))
    } catch (error) {
      let showMessage = error.message
      if (error.message.indexOf('account-exists-with-different-credential') > -1) {
        showMessage = translate('ERROR_ALREADY_REGISTERED', {
          provider: 'Facebook'
        })
      }
      notifyMessage(showMessage)
      this.props.stopLoading()
    }
  }
render () {
<RoundedButton onPress={() => { this._onGoogleButtonPress() }} size={100} padding={22} image={require('../../assets/google.png')} />
}
```

My problem is that I have like 10-15 users more which are trying to access the app.
I don't have any idea who they are

[image]

Did anybody faced that ? 
I am wondering if it is not a kind of test Google does for the apps or I don't know. If somebody have some details on that would be appreciated.

Comment: are Apple ID users, have you enabled them to login in your firebase console?

Comment: Nop all incriminated users are google users, and yes I enabled signin for apple (which seems to working well), google and facebook.